# UINavigationBar Title and Buttons disappear after gradient is applied on iOS 11 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10, ios11

I have recently upgraded to Xcode 9 with Swift 4 which has in turn updated all the iOS emulators. 
Since the update, I have found that after I apply a gradient to the UINavigationBar; the title and buttons do not appear, yet still have functionality.

Here is the code to applying my gradient -

```
extension UIView {

    func applyNavGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> Void {
       self.applyNavGradient(colours: colours, locations: nil)
    }

    func applyNavGradient(colours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> Void {
       let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
       gradient.frame = self.bounds
       gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
       gradient.locations = locations
       self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
       self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    } 
}

class ViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            UINavigationBar.applyNavGradient(colours: redFade)
        }
```

This used to work in Xcode 8 with iOS10 -

[image: Before iOS 9]

Now all I get is this;

[image: With iOS 9]

Can anyone give me some clue as to why this has changed??

Thank you in advance!

Chris.

Comment: how do you set your title and buttons in your `UINavigationBar` - can you add this code as well?

Comment: Yeah sure/ The button is set in the Storyboard and never changes. 
The title is its own UINavigationItem and is set like;
`self.navTitle.title ="My Application"`

Comment: What has changed in IOS11 is that custom controls in navigation must have constrains or must report it's size. If you fail to do that your control will have zero size.

Comment: Okay. I see, I'll give it a go when I get back in.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason I cannot get it to work. It will not let me add constraints, nor will it allow me to set a size for it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIColor.init(patternImage image: UIImage)` method to assign `barTintColor` of `navigationBar`

**Here is the sample code**

```
func applyNavGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> UIImage? {

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.origin.y)
    gradientLayer.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image

}
```

**After that you can call like this to set gradient**

```
if let img = applyNavGradient(colours: [UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow]) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: img)
}
```